# Change a REMOTE web.config programmatically in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I have two web project hosted on same server that is One site User & Admin Projects.I want to dynamically change the values of App Setting (Key of app setting)

I know how to change the value web.config value programmatically in Same Project.But how different project,

```
System.Configuration.ExeConfigurationFileMap configFile = new System.Configuration.ExeConfigurationFileMap();
configFile.ExeConfigFilename = "ConsoleTester.exe.config";  //name of your config file, can be from your app or external
System.Configuration.Configuration config = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configFile, System.Configuration.ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
System.Configuration.KeyValueConfigurationCollection settings = config.AppSettings.Settings;
settings["DD"].Value = "007_Access";
config.Save();
```

Comment: Well, like basic path traversal? `..\OtherApp\some.config`? What have you tried? Why do you want to do this in the first place? Apps shouldn't write into each other's configs.

Comment: Assuming you provide the correct path in `ExeConfigFileName` and that you have the right permissions (don't forget that to read/write something outside site root directory is forbidden by default) then it should work. However, I think that's a risky practice. Why don't you expose a service to do it from your App? Service itself may (should!) be enabled only for local requests.

Comment: ExeConfigurationFileMap has an overloaded constructor that accepts a path. Completely untested though.

Answer (score 1):

What I get of your problem is, You have one codebase and you need to serve two application instance with different functionalities.

> First of all its not good idea to modify your web.config at runtime.

To have two application instance based on one codebase with separated web.config, you can use virtual directory feature of IIS. 
create two web-application on IIS with two web.config(separated directory) and then define a virtual directory pointed to your codebase.

Comment: Actually i want I have a 2 Web project. 1 web project is access to users & Other one is Admin access.When my client(admin) want to put a Site on maintenance mode or temporarily un accessible mode.How can i do it in admin app?

Comment: Actually to make website offile, simply you can use asp.net offline feature, just create a ```app_offline.htm``` at your project root directory. the name is case sensitive. you can checkout this [link](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/426755).

Answer (score 1):

In IIS 7+ there is a C# API that allows you to create applications, and modify configs.

The documentation is here [Microsoft.Web.Administration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/scripting/accessing-configuration-sections-using-microsoftwebadministration-mwa)

I think this code should get you there abouts:

```
   var serverManager = new ServerManager();
   var site = serverManager.Sites["SiteName"];
   var app = site.Applications["MyAppName"];
   var config = app.GetWebConfiguration();
   var section = config.GetSection("appSettings");
   var element = section.GetChildElement("mySettingKey");
   element.SetAttributeValue("value", "MyNewValue");
   serverManager.CommitChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a `app_offline.htm` file which will take your site down. All you have to do is place the file in the root directory of your website and IIS will do the rest for you. You can add a maintenance message on the `app_offline.htm` and do maintenance while the users will see only the `app_offline.htm` page

If you would really wanna go programmatically. You can rename the file to something else when its not needed and rename it back to `app_offline.htm` when you wanna take the site down.